# Hive/Impala column-comments cut off after several characters

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, impala, hive-metastore

When I take a look at the column-comments in our Data Lake (Hadoop, comments made during parquet-table creation with Hive or Impala) they are cut of after ~200 characters.

Might this be a global character-setting in our hadoop-system or some Hive-restriction? If not, is there a way to set the maximum-string-length for comments during the table creation? Unfortunately, I have no admin-access to the system itself and, therefore, restricted insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column comments are stored in Hive Metastore table `COLUMNS_V2`, in a column called `COMMENT`. 
Currently, the size of that column is limited to 256 characters (see [MySQL metastore schema definition](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/standalone-metastore/metastore-server/src/main/sql/mysql/hive-schema-3.0.0.mysql.sql#L54) for Hive version 3.0.0 for example). 
In the upcoming 4.0 (?) version, it seems to have been expanded to varchar(4000), but associated Hive [JIRA-4921](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4921) is still listed as unresolved, and doesn't mention a target release #.

Comment: Oh what a bummer that this cannot be set by the user itself :( Nonetheless, thank you for your fast answer and explanation!